# Proper way to identify a Windows Phone device

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I'm using the following code to retrieve the devices attached to my computer

```
string aqsFilter = "System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{6AC27878-A6FA-4155-BA85-F98F491D4F33}\" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True";
var interfaces = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter,propertiesToGet);

foreach (var item in interfaces)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    foreach (var p in item.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", p.Key, p.Value);
    }
}
```

Is there a property I can rely on to know exactly if the device is a Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Environment.OSVersion?

```
 string os = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
```

for more take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: My code does not run on the device... from a Windows desktop app I need to know if there's a valid Windows Phone device attached to the computer.